# different CSS transition after toggleClass

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

Salutations all

I made this pen recently https://codepen.io/alexyap/full/MmYvLw/ and I am stumped on my nav menu. It's working fine when it transitions in but looks just horrible when it fades out. I just can't figure this part out.

```
<div id="nav-container" class="hidden">
 <ul>
  <li id="nav1" class="hidden"><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li id="nav2" class="hidden"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
  <li id="nav3" class="hidden"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

```css
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-left: -60%;
}
```

JS:

```js
$("#nav-container").delay(200).queue(function(n){
      $(this).toggleClass("hidden")
      n()
    })

    $("#nav1").delay(400).queue(function(n){
      $(this).toggleClass("hidden")
      n()
    })

    $("#nav2").delay(600).queue(function(n){
      $(this).toggleClass("hidden")
      n()
    })

    $("#nav3").delay(800).queue(function(n){
      $(this).toggleClass("hidden")
      n()
    })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It works fine if I take the class of hidden out from the #nav-container but it blocks my CTA button on the landing page when I do that. What I am trying to go for is after hitting the menu button which turns into an 'X', my nav menu links should transition out one after another just like when it transitions it without me having to add the class of hidden back to the #nav-container again. I'm sorry if I'm not making any sense. English is not my native language but just please try to look at my pen and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this is to put the transitions into the CSS instead and simply toggle a class on a container. We'll use the `transition-delay` property to handle the sequential timing effect you want. Below is an example.

Relevant HTML:

```
<div id="menu-overlay"></div>
<div id="menu-button-container">
  <div id="menu-button">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="nav-container">
  <ul>
    <li id="nav1"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li id="nav2"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li id="nav3"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
#menu-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(52, 73, 94,1.0);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: .5s ease-in 1200ms;
  z-index: 2000;
}
.showing #menu-overlay {
  transition: .5s ease-in 0s;
}
.reveal {
  height: 100vh !important;
}
#nav-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -10;
  transition-property: z-index;
  transition-delay: 1200ms;
}
.showing #nav-container {
  z-index: 2000;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
#nav-container ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-left: -60%;
}
.showing #nav-container ul li {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  margin-left: 0;
}
#nav1 {
  transition: 0.6s ease-in 200ms;
}
#nav2 {
  transition: 0.6s ease-in 400ms;
}
#nav3 {
  transition: 0.6s ease-in 600ms;
}
```

Relevant JS:

```
$('#menu-button').click(function(){
  $('body').toggleClass('showing');
});
```

Comment: wow! this is perfect although there is more thing, the CTA button on the landing page isn't clickable still with this method nor does my hover effect take effect when you hover over it. that was my initial problem which was why i had to make the #nav-container "invisible" by playing around with the visibility property because it's "blocking" the CTA button. Try to inspect the page to see what I mean and I'm sorry if I'm not able to explain any clearer.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I didn't notice that. We can fix that by manipulating the `z-index` of `#nav-container` in a similar fashion as we changed the properties of `#menu-overlay` based on whether or not the body has the `showing` class. I've edited the answer. See if that'll work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, I'm pretty sure it will work. Also, you just gave me a fantastic idea for another experiment I want to try out. Again, thank you. You've helped me heaps. I believe I've given you credit for your answer. I'm not sure lol. I'm still pretty new here.

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped. I'm not seeing the answer as marked checked, though. Should be a little gray checkmark under the arrows by my answer you can click to turn it green. Also upvote the answer, if you would :)

Comment: Great! Can you also upvote the answer? Appreciate it.

Comment: I did but apparently I don't have enough credits to my name yet for it to display

Comment: Oh no worries. It'll show up eventually then. Just figured I'd ask in case. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to transfer the to the mobile screen, these are the codes I used

```js
const header = docment.querySelctor("header");
window.addEventListener ("scroll", function(){
      header.classList.toggle ("sticky", this.window.scrollY > 0);
})

let menu = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
let navmenu = document.querySelector('.navmenu');

menu.onclick = () => {
      menu.classList.toggle('bx-x');
      navmenu.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px 10%;
}
.logo img{
    max-width: 120px;
    height: auto;
}
.navmenu{
    display: flex;
}
.navmenu a{
    color: #474141;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    transform: all .42s ease ;
}
.navmenu a:hover{
    color: #EE1C47;
}
.nav-icon{
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
}
.nav-icon i{
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: #2c2c2c;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 400;
    transition: all .42s ease;
}
.nav-icon i:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    color: #EE1C47;
}
#menu-icon{
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #2c2c2c;
    z-index: 10001;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
 <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="example.jpg" alt=""></a>

        <ul class="navmenu">
            <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="nav-icon">
            <a href="#"><i class='bx bx-search'></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class='bx bx-user'></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class='bx bx-cart'></i></a>

            <div class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-icon"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
```